# Can't launch Android app from the terminal: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial starting Intent - not exported

Tags: android, adb

We have a Xamarin app that I am attempting to write automated UI tests for, and to do I need to programmatically launch the app via a terminal (using Appium).  When I attempt to do so, I get this error:

```
An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot start the 'com.company.android' application. Visit https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md for troubleshooting. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command '/Users/kroe761/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell am start -W -n com.company.android/crc6483c3a7691f3846e9.MainActivity -S -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -f 0x10200000' exited with code 255'; Stderr: 'Security exception: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.company.android/crc6483c3a7691f3846e9.MainActivity } from null (pid=4310, uid=2000) not exported from uid 10134
     
       java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.company.android/crc6483c3a7691f3846e9.MainActivity } from null (pid=4310, uid=2000) not exported from uid 10134
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStackSupervisor.checkStartAnyActivityPermission(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1043)
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.startActivity(ActivityStarter.java:760)
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.startActivity(ActivityStarter.java:583)
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStarter.java:1288)
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.execute(ActivityStarter.java:514)
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskManagerService.startActivityAndWait(ActivityTaskManagerService.java:1231)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAndWait(ActivityManagerService.java:3512)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerShellCommand.runStartActivity(ActivityManagerShellCommand.java:513)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerShellCommand.onCommand(ActivityManagerShellCommand.java:172)
        at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:104)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onShellCommand(ActivityManagerService.java:9774)
        at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:881)
        at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:765)
        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:4498)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2741)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1021)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:994)'; Code: '255'
```

I can't figure out what the problem could be, but I do think it might be something related to the AndroidManifest.xml.  In case it's relevant, here is ours:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:versionCode="566"
    android:versionName="2021.01.13"
    package="com.company.android"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize|adjustPan">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="25"
        android:targetSdkVersion="30" />

    <application
        android:label="Company"
        android:icon="@mipmap/icon"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:resizeableActivity="true"
        android:supportsRtl="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="smsto"/>
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>
```

Comment: You don't have any activities in your manifest.  Its trying to launch the launcher activity, and nothing in your manifest matches that intent filter

Answer (score 5):

Try to add this to your manifest (inside the `<application>...</application>` section), this will export your Activity and you will be allowed to open it elsewhere.

```
<activity>
    android:name="YOUR.PACKAGE.MainActivity"
    android:exported="true"
</activity>
```